# How do I make Windows to stop uplugging and replugging my keyboard causing keystrokes to disappear

Tags: windows, usb

When I'm typing, I can hear Windows unplug and replug a USB device randomly. During this time my keystrokes disappear. They do not suddenly show up afterwards, instead they disappear entirely. My keyboard is plugged into a USB-C hub. The keyboard does not automatically unplug and replug on my Linux machine.

I'm on Windows 10 and have restarted my computer this morning, so I am 100% confident that I have the latest and greatest updates available.

How can I make Windows accept all my keystrokes?

Comment: Try a different USB Port and/or a different Keyboard. See if that helps.

Comment: Please provide the last cumlative update you last installed?  When did the keyboard start behaving this way?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0):

[Minitool.com](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery/usb-keeps-disconnecting.html) suggests reinstalling the Universal Serial Bus controllers driver, turning off Power Saving option for the USB driver, and installing Universal Serial Bus controllers driver in Compatibility mode. That said, I've had similar issues where the *USB hub* was at fault, too:

- Try plugging *directly* into a PC port. Some hubs I've used seem to disconnect and reconnect... perhaps a loose power cord, or loose connectors inside.
- Mounting the hub and wires to a piece of perforated metal, using double-stick tape and wire ties, helped in one case. The reason to use metal was also to alleviate overheating, which might also have been part of the problem.

Yes, the issue did not appear in Linux, but that might be because Linux is more fault-tolerant, or because it better manages power to USB ports. It's worth a few minutes to check if the *hardware* fix helps. Let us know if the hub, indeed, is the cause.